# If $f\left(0\right)=1$ and $f'\left(x\right)>3f\left(x\right)\ $ $∀\ x\ \ge0$ then prove that $f\left(x\right)\ge e^{3x}\ ∀\ x\ \ge0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Q:**

> $f\left(x\right)$ is a continuous and differentiable function defined in $[0,\infty)$. If $f\left(0\right)=1$ and $f'\left(x\right)>3f\left(x\right)\ $ $∀\ x\ \ge0$ then prove that $f\left(x\right)\ge e^{3x}\ ∀\ x\ \ge0$

**Approach:**

> Given $$f'\left(x\right)>3f\left(x\right)\ $$
> Let $f\left(x\right)=t$, $$\to\frac{dt}{dx}>3t\ \to\frac{dt}{t}>3dx$$
> since $t\ (or f(x)) >0$, equality sign doesn't remain same.
> $$\ln t>3x+C$$
> Put $x=0\ \to f\left(0\right)=1$,
> We get,  $$\ln1>0+C$$
> $$0>0+C$$

What do I do now, how shall I proceed further, where am I wrong?

Also, $t\ (or f(x)) >0$ because $f\left(0\right)=1$ and $f'\left(x\right)>3f\left(x\right)\ $ so $f'\left(x\right)$ is always positive so function only takes positive values.

Need help

Comment: Try defining $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{e^{3x}}$ and see where that takes you.

Comment: Show that $g(x)\geq 1$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$ by showing $g(0)=1$ and $g$ is increasing.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thank you for your reply, I'll try and update my progress. Edit: With the help of your hint, I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$g\left(x\right)=\frac{f\left(x\right)}{e^{3x}}\to g\left(0\right)=\frac{f\left(0\right)}{e^{0}}\to g\left(0\right)=1$$
Now, $$g'\left(x\right)=\frac{f'\left(x\right)-3f\left(x\right)}{e^{3x}}$$
Since, $f'\left(x\right)-3f\left(x\right)>0\ $ for all $x∈[0,∞)$, $g'\left(x\right)>0$ in x $∈[0,∞)$

Thus, $$g\left(x\right)\ge1$$and so
$$f\left(x\right)\ge e^{3x}\ in\ x∈[0,∞)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(x)\ge 0$ such that

$$
f'(x)-p(x) = 3f(x)
$$

Using the Laplace transform we have

$$
(s-3)F(s) = P(s)+f(0)\Rightarrow F(s) = \frac{1}{s+3}P(s)+\frac{1}{s+3}f(0)
$$

or inverting

$$
f(x) = e^{3x}\circledast p(x)+f(0)e^{3x}
$$

now as $f(0) = 1$ and $e^{3x}\circledast p(x)\ge 0$ we have that

$$
f(x) \ge e^{3x}
$$